# Multiple Hive joins failing with Execution Error, return code 2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I'm trying to execute a query in which a table is left outer joined on two other tables. The query is given below:

```
SELECT T.Rdate, c.Specialty_Cruises, b.Specialty_Cruises from arunf.PASSENGER_HISTORY_FACT T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN arunf.RPT_WEB_COURTESY_HOLD_TEMP C on (unix_timestamp(T.RDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd')=unix_timestamp(c.rdate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AND T.book_num = c.Courtesy_Hold_Booking_Num) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN arunf.RPT_WEB_BOOKING_NUM_TEMP b ON (unix_timestamp(T.RDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd')=unix_timestamp(b.rdate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AND T.book_num = B.Online_Booking_Number);
```

**This query fails with the notification:**

```
: exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(922)) - /tmp/arunf/hive.log
: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(308)) - Execution failed with exit status: 2
: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(922)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
```

**The error logs contain the following:**

```
2015-12-01 10:25:16,077 INFO  [main]: mr.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(913)) - Execution log at: /tmp/arunf/arunf_20151201102525_914a2eab-652b-440c-9fdc-a473b4caa026.log
2015-12-01 10:25:16,278 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(118)) - <PERFLOG method=deserializePlan from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities>
2015-12-01 10:25:16,278 INFO  [main]: exec.Utilities (Utilities.java:deserializePlan(953)) - Deserializing MapredLocalWork via kryo
2015-12-01 10:25:16,421 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(158)) - </PERFLOG method=deserializePlan start=1448983516278 end=1448983516421 duration=143 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities>
2015-12-01 10:25:16,429 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (SessionState.java:printInfo(913)) - 2015-12-01 10:25:16   Starting to launch local task to process map join;  maximum memory = 1029701632
2015-12-01 10:25:16,498 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:initializeOperators(441)) - fetchoperator for c created
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:initializeOperators(441)) - fetchoperator for b created
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initialize(346)) - Initializing Self TS[2]
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(419)) - Operator 2 TS initialized
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(423)) - Initializing children of 2 TS
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: exec.HashTableSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(458)) - Initializing child 1 HASHTABLESINK
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initialize(394)) - Initialization Done 2 TS
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:initializeOperators(461)) - fetchoperator for b initialized
2015-12-01 10:25:16,500 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initialize(346)) - Initializing Self TS[0]
2015-12-01 10:25:16,501 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(419)) - Operator 0 TS initialized
2015-12-01 10:25:16,501 INFO  [main]: exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(423)) - Initializing children of 0 TS
2015-12-01 10:25:16,502 INFO  [main]: exec.HashTableSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(458)) - Initializing child 1 HASHTABLESINK
2015-12-01 10:25:16,503 INFO  [main]: exec.HashTableSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(346)) - Initializing Self HASHTABLESINK[1]
2015-12-01 10:25:16,503 INFO  [main]: mapjoin.MapJoinMemoryExhaustionHandler (MapJoinMemoryExhaustionHandler.java:<init>(61)) - JVM Max Heap Size: 1029701632
2015-12-01 10:25:16,533 ERROR [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInProcess(357)) - Hive Runtime Error: Map local work failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field courtesy_hold_booking_num from [0:rdate, 1:online_booking_number, 2:pages, 3:mobile_device_type, 4:specialty_cruises]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils.getStandardStructFieldRef(ObjectInspectorUtils.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.BaseStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldRef(BaseStructObjectInspector.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinUtil.getObjectInspectorsFromEvaluators(JoinUtil.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.HashTableSinkOperator.initializeOp(HashTableSinkOperator.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.initializeOperators(MapredLocalTask.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.startForward(MapredLocalTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.executeInProcess(MapredLocalTask.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:743)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

**Please note that, when the main table is left outer joined with the tables separately they succeed**.
Example, the below queries succeed:

```
SELECT T.Rdate from arunf.PASSENGER_HISTORY_FACT T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN arunf.RPT_WEB_COURTESY_HOLD_TEMP C on (unix_timestamp(T.RDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd')=unix_timestamp(c.rdate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AND T.book_num = c.Courtesy_Hold_Booking_Num);

SELECT T.Rdate from arunf.PASSENGER_HISTORY_FACT T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN arunf.RPT_WEB_BOOKING_NUM_TEMP b ON (unix_timestamp(T.RDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd')=unix_timestamp(b.rdate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AND T.book_num = B.Online_Booking_Number);
```

I'm also able to do a left outer join of this main table with two other tables in the same combined manner. I'm facing this issue only when I try to left join the main table with these two secondary tables.

Kindly provide your insights on this issue.

Comment: The columns shown in your sample queries and the columns listed in the error message are completely different. Either you tried to "hide" the actual queries, or you pasted the wrong log, or your Hive Metastore is completely broken...

Comment: BTW, there is a "code sample" format. Don't be shy, use it. It makes code samples sooooo much easier to read.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, thanks for pointing that out. I was using dummy tables to troubleshoot the issue and i had posted them, the logs for which have been overwritten now. So i'm posting the actual code for the given logs. Please let me know if you need anymore info. I have now quoted the queries as a code segment, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive bugs come and go. It may depend on Hive version (?) and the table format (text? AVRO? Sequence? ORC? Parquet?).

Now, if each query appears to work, why don't you **try a workaround** based on the divide-and-conquer approach *(or: if Hive is not smart enough to design an execution plan, then let's design it ourselves)* e.g.

```
SELECT TC.RDate, TC.Specialty_Cruises, B.Specialty_Cruises
FROM
 (SELECT T.Rdate, C.Specialty_Cruises
  FROM arunf.PASSENGER_HISTORY_FACT T
  LEFT JOIN arunf.RPT_WEB_COURTESY_HOLD_TEMP C
   ON unix_timestamp(T.RDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')=unix_timestamp(C.RDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')
  AND T.book_num = C.Courtesy_Hold_Booking_Num
 ) TC
LEFT JOIN arunf.RPT_WEB_BOOKING_NUM_TEMP B
 ON unix_timestamp(TC.RDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')=unix_timestamp(B.RDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')
AND TC.book_num = B.Online_Booking_Number
;
```

Comment: I tried that out earlier and that worked. I have to use this chunk of query within another big hive query which left joins joins 7 other tables. So it gets a little tricky when I have to use nested joins in this scenario. Another round about method is to load the output of this nested join query into a temporary table and then use the temporary table in the main query. Either way, I'm now able to proceed now. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: One last thing: did you consider Pig instead of Hive? Could be a better fit for this use case *(multi-step process w/ intermediate results)*. I don't have enough practise w/ Pig on real-world data to give an informed advice, though

Comment: same is the case with me too. I don't have enough practical exposure to Pig. So I decided not to venture into unknown waters when time was precious. I'm pretty sure this would not be a problem in Impala too. When I get sometime, I'm going to do some R&D with this in Impala.